# Procesamiento de querys en Spring - Duda

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, spring, buenas-prácticas

tengo la siguiente duda.
Que es mas eficiente, tratar una query lo mas simple posible o con cruces de informacion ya desde la etapa de extraccion de informacion.
me explico. supongamos que tenemos esta query:

```
SELECT CAMPO1, CAMPO2, CAMPO3, ...
FROM TABLA A; --Se mapea la tabla en spring

SELECT CAMPO1, CAMPO2, CAMPO3, ...
FROM TABLA B; -- Se mapea la tabla en spring
```

Luego la informacion que tenemos aqui la cruzamos con otra tabla mediante spring.

O en dado caso ya hacer los join de un inicio.

```
 SELECT CAMPO1, CAMPO2, CAMPO3, ...
    FROM TABLA A 
    Inner join TABLA B on a.id = b.id ... -- Se mapea ya desde esta manera
```

ahora para ser mas claro, supongamos que tenemos 4 o 5 tablas, y necesitamos validar informacion que este en todas.

A) Tratar los datos de forma individual por tabla

B) Traer los datos ya listos para ser procesados, agregando joins o sub querys.

Por tema de eficiencia, buenas practicas, cual recomiendan?

Realmente no es solo en spring, ya que, esta situacion se puede dar basicamente en cualquier lenguaje o herramiente que conecte con una base de datos usando modelo de capas.

Comment: hola, así como está planteada la pregunta se puede considerar de opinión por lo cuál puede ser cerrada. Por otra parte, si hablamos de eficiencia siempre va a ser mejor tener los datos procesados o "empaquetados" por ejemplo utilizando vistas en la BD, que además pueden ser materializadas lo cual agrega la posibilidad de generarle índices para las búsquedas, entre otras cosas.Siempre he sido de la vertiente de delegar a la bd lo más que se pueda en terminos de búsqueda y visualización de datos. Pensar que accediendo tabla por tabla es hacer query por query, petición por petición...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitivamente B, y no considero que se trate de una cuestión de opinión porque se puede demostrar la eficiencia con un simple ejemplo, coincidiendo con la opinión de @zerocool: supongamos que quieres contar el número de registros de una tabla, ¿traerías todos los registros del servidor de bases de datos a tu máquina para contarlos con tu programa? ¿O pedirías directamente el número total de registros transfiriendo únicamente un entero? Sé que es un ejemplo llevado al extremo, pero se trata de transmitir la idea claramente: todo lo que puedas hacer con la base de datos, hazlo con el motor de la base de datos. Piensa que, de esta forma, todos los datos que necesitas para realizar el cálculo van entre disco y memoria de la máquina del servidor de datos, no tienes que moverlos a la máquina que ejecuta tu programa.

Espero no haber malinterpretado tu pregunta. Quedo a tu disposición para aclarar cualquier extremo.

Comment: Por favor, indícanos si esta respuesta ha aclarado tu duda y de qué forma podemos ampliarla para que también pueda ayudar a otras personas en tu misma situación. Has hecho un esfuerzo planteando la pregunta, no lo dejemos a medio camino. [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)